# Api Platform access_control : adding role is not working

Tags: api, symfony, access-control, api-platform.com, symfony-4.3

I am building a symfony 4 cmf. I am using API Platform. 
In the page.php entity, i have added the following

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

 /**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"write"}},
 *     collectionOperations={"get"},
 *     itemOperations={
 *       "get",
 *       "put"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"},
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PageRepository")
 */
 class Page
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Groups("write")
 */
private $route;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Groups({"read", "write"})
 */
private $name;
.....
```

**NOTE**
In my normal back office controllers, i'm already using voters, and IS_GRANTED. I'm trying to say that my access control is working perfectly at other places except in my API PLATFORM entities.

Right now, even though i've added the ROLE_ADMIN to the PUT method, I authenticate with a ROLE_USER only user, and i'm being able to PUT the page. This means that it is not taking my ROLE in the is_granted section of the ApiPlatform annotation into consideration.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it still matters, but try:

```
"put"={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"},
```